# fopen $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]

Tags: php, fopen

I need to `fopen` a file with the same name as the url with '.txt' at the end.

I have this: `fopen("$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI].txt", 'a+')`

but I think the forward slash at the beginning of the url is messing things up.

Comment: What happens when you run this? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably trim the URI, however this looks ... highly insecure.

```
$filename = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");
$filename .= ".txt";

$handle = fopen($filename, "a+");
```

To clarify why this is insecure, people could use this to access, potentially, any file in that directory.

You should probably have an array of "allowed files" that people may access, and then check to see if the given file is in that array. For example:

```
$allowed_files = array(
    "file1.txt",
    "file2.txt",
);

$filename = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");
$filename .= ".txt";

if(in_array($filename, $allowed_files)){
    //Success, so they may view the file
    $handle = fopen($filename, "a+");
}else{
    //Failure, they may not
    return false;
}
```

To keep it generic, try this:

```
//Validate the filename
$filename = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$slashes = explode("/", $filename);
$filename = $slashes[1];
$filename .= ".txt";

$handle = fopen($filename, "a+");
```

Comment: What makes it highly insecure? I'm still learning php so be gentle.

Comment: Well the REQUEST_URI can have anything in it, so people could potentially access files that you don't want them to.

Comment: Would using SCRIPT_NAME instead of REQUEST_URI be considered safe?

Comment: I want to be able to use it in a generic way and avoid lists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use the `__FILE__` constant:

```
$fp = fopen(preg_replace('/\..+$/', '.txt', __FILE__), 'a+');
```

Of course, your code would have to be on the correct page.